# angularjs submit form on select change event

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I'm using django in the back-end. I need to submit a form with a language parameter and refresh the page to change the language in the front-end.

I've got a select tag which is nested inside a form.

```
<form>
   ...
   <select name="language" ng-model="selectedLanguage" ng-options="language in languages" ng-change="changeLanguage()">
   ...
</form>
```

I'd like to submit the form on select change event, what's the best way to do it with angularjs?

The `$event` object is not available for the change event (angular 1.3.0).

Comment: Why don't you use AJAX instead of submitting the form?

Comment: The back-end is in django and the translations are rendered via django trans tags

Comment: I think you should mention something how you are using django in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Have a `$scope.$watch` for `selectedLanguage` and call the submit function whenever it changes.

**Edit**

In case you want to do form submit

you can use [angular.element.find](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) to find your form. 
( But im not sure why you need angular in case you are making a form submit)

Comment: That's what ng-change does right now. I'd like to know how to make a reference to the form which is inside the controller to submit it manually, I cannot make an ajax call in this case.